# How to get ViewId dynamically in android

Tags: android, view, dynamically-generated

How to get the ID of dynamically created View in android ?  Actually I have many views in my layout and i want the id of that view which is touched by user. It it possible? if Yes than how to do it?

In the following code new Frame Layout is created, I have generateViewId for this layout and save this id as key to HashMap (logoResizingRecordList).

```
 FrameLayout fm=new FrameLayout(getApplication());
 FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400,300);
                    fm.addView(img_pinch,params);

 int FrameLayoutID=fm.generateViewId();

 logoResizingRecordList.put(FrameLayoutID,logoObj);
 fm.setOnTouchListener(logoTouchListner);
```

Here OnTouch I have assign instance of FrameLayout to temp_img_logo.

```
public boolean onTouch(final View p_v, MotionEvent p_event)
    {            
        if(p_v instanceof FrameLayout) {           
            temp_img_logo=(FrameLayout)p_v;
        }
```

here I want to get the id of the above FrameLayout (fm) But it return the default Id of any View i.e -1

```
logoResizingRecordList.get(temp_img_logo.getId())
```

Now my question is that is it possible to get the id of fm (FrameLayout) that i have created dynamically? If yes then please help me out to find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically created"? Do you mean that you are using the constructor on the `View` subclasses (e.g., `new Button(...)`)? Do you mean that you are using `LayoutInflater`? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CommosWare dynamically means that TextView are created programatically and then add it into the layout. now I want to get the id of this textview on OnTouch event.

Comment: What do you mean by "are created programatically"? Do you mean that you are using the constructor on the `View` subclasses (e.g., `new Button(...)`)? Do you mean that you are using `LayoutInflater`? Do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not generate ID dynamically. You have to do it by yourself.

A simple example that will help you:

```
public static final int TEXT_VIEW1_ID = 1001;

TextView textView1 = new TextView(Context);
textView1.setId(TEXT_VIEW1_ID);

relativeLayout.addView(textView1);
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if(view.getId() == TEXT_VIEW1_ID){
            Toast.makeText(context, "TextView1 was touched.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set the onclick listener for all of this to a single listener and do a switch of the arg1.getId() of the onclick method

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

First , In order to get the id, you have to set the id,

```
TextView txt  = new TextView(context);
txt.setId(some integer);
```

Then you have to keep the dynamic views with in somewhere like array or list.
Then You can get the position which was touched and get the relevant view id as follows,

```
int id = textViewList.get(position).getId();
```

Comment: if i have textView and i set the OnTouch listener on it then the ID of View parameter of OnTouch Listener  and the ID of TextView both are same or not? i am getting different ID's please help me out.